# Parse html string in java servlet

Tags: java, html, parsing, dom, servlets

I am trying to parse below string in java servlet.

```
<con>
   <status>OK</status>
   <session>12312332432</session>
 </con>
```

I want value of `<session>` element.

Ideas ?

Comment: That is an entire String ?

Comment: Looks an awful lot like XML this..

Comment: original string is very big. this is just sample

Comment: @Deckard27 getElementByTagName??

Comment: @Deckard27 - You thinking JS not Java?

Comment: you can not access dom in servlet

Comment: sry i mistake i read dom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's not XML, you can use regex:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

String aParser="<con><status>OK</status><session>12312332432</session></con>";
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("<session>(.*)</session>");
Matcher m=p.matcher(aParser);

while(m.find())
{ 
   System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For XML purposes you should use an XMLParser.

Look at SAXParser it will do the job.

SAXParser is very good when dealing with big files, because the whole document isn´t hold
in memory.

Comment: its not XML. its just html string

Comment: The String you posted can be parsed with an XML Parser.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need session value and not the entire XMl data.just split() the string as below

xmlString.split(starttag)[1].split(endtag)[0];